# OpenGl Rotate object on Y axis to look at another object

Tags: opengl, math, rotation, glsl, angle

So like in a topic I got 2 objects one i moving around (on z and x axis) the other one is static but should rotate around y axis to always like a look at the other... and i am fighting with this already a week

what i got now is

vector from 1object to 2object and actual look at(also vector) of the 2object
i'am calculating angel betwean this two vectors and adding this to rotattion.y of the 2 object but its not working properly

any idea how to make it work? btw i'am using eular angel transforms

pseudCode:

```
vectorFrom1to2 = vector1 - vector2;
lookatVectorof2ndObject;
```

i normalize both of them and then

```
float angle = acos(dot(vectorFrom1to2, lookatVectorof2ndObject));
object2.rotateY = angle;
```

i dont know where i do mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, which proved itself true in many situations I observed is: As soon as you find yourself calculating *angles* from vectors, you are most likely doing something in a more unnecessarily complicated way than necessary.

All you need is a basis transformation which transforms the first object's local coordinate system to make its local Z axis point towards the second object. You can do this with a simple rotation matrix (provided you have a matrix/vector library ready to facilitate this more easily).

So, provided you have object 1 with position `p1` and object 2 with position `p2` and you want `p1` to rotate towards `p2`, then the rotation matrix can be obtained as follows:

(I am just using GLSL pseudo syntax here)

```
vec3 p1 = ... // <- position of first object
vec3 p2 = ... // <- position of second object
vec3 d = normalize(p2 - p1)
vec3 r = cross(vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), d)
       = vec3(d.z, 0, -d.x)
mat3 m = mat3(d.z, 0, -d.x, // <- first column ('right' vector)
              0, 1, 0,      // <- second column (keep Y)
              d.x, 0, d.z)  // <- third column (map Z to point towards p2)
```

When transforming the vertices `v` of the first object with `m` by: `v' = m * v` you get the Z axis of object `p1` to point towards the position of `p2`, all formulated in the same "world" coordinate system.

Comment: Man Thank you! its is way better then i tried to do this! and it Worked!